# C++ type trait to extract specialization value of template argument

Tags: c++, c++11, type-traits

I have following template:

```
template<typename T, const char *name_ >
struct named {
  typedef T type;
  static constexpr const char *name = name_;
};
```

I'd like to have type traits which:

- would extract type and name (2 different) if argument type is "named"
- would extract original type and empty string if argument is different
  type.

Example:

```
template<typename T>
void foo() {
  typename cppdi::extract_type<T>::type x;

  std::cout << "type: " << typeid(x).name() <<
               ", name: " << cppdi::extract_name<T>::value << std::endl;
}

char bar[] = "bar";

void test() {
  foo<int>();             // type: i, name:
  foo<named<int, bar>>(); // type: i, name: bar
}
```

Is it possible to implement such `extract_type` and `extract_name`?

Comment: It helps to post code snippets that compile.  I am going to edit them to be less broken, feel free to revert if they don't match your thoughts.

Comment: Edited it myself after checking Daniel's answer :)

Comment: @Daimon I think I just realized what the "missing" `typedef`-confusion was about: You only apply `typeid()` to an expression (a variable), while the variable itself in your code is superfluous. It also explains why you asked for `extract_type<...>::value` instead of `extract_type<T>::type`. You know that you can also apply `typeid()` to a type *directly*? This is what I did in my live example in the answer, see also [typeid operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid) on http://cppreference.com/

Comment: In real usage I'm using extract_type just to get type - used typeid in example just to visualize what I meant - and of course you are right I did it wrong :) but in target code it's being used properly. Thx again for answer about traits

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Write your traits like this:

```
template< typename T >
struct extract_type
{ using type = T; };

template< typename T, const char* S >
struct extract_type< named< T, S > >
{ using type = T; };

template< typename T >
struct extract_name
{ static constexpr const char* value = ""; };

template< typename T, const char* S >
struct extract_name< named< T, S > >
{ static constexpr const char* value = S; };
```

That alone won't work, the code you gave is illegal in several places. I fixed them in this [**live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/10c0da527c146ac5).

Comment: I had to read your answer to understand the question, but the solution to the presumed question is great ;-)

Comment: Thx, had to modify original question a bit, but your traits work great